# mysql get max number in condition first two digits from user

Tags: mysql

i need get maximum number start with first two digit
like example

```
    id    year id
    1      14001
    2      14002
    3      14003
    4      13001 
    5      13002
```

if i need max number which start from 13
the result i want maximum number is 13002
I've tried, but it doesn't work.
thanks in advance

Comment: what you want to show? and i a bit confused on your comment.

Comment: i want show max number which starts from two digits same

Comment: only get one result on 13? or even 14 you also want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(`year id`) as MaxVal FROM TableName
WHERE CAST(`year id` as CHAR(50)) LIKE '13%'
```

Result:

```
MAXVAL
13002
```

See result in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e973/15).

Comment: I would highly recommend `WHERE year_id BETWEEN 13000 AND 13999`